# Call Dial Screen in iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode6

I want to have a screen exactly similar to the call dial screen on the call App on the iOS app that I am developing. Is there a way to have that screen in the app without actually implementing it?

If not, what would be the best way to design it? I have been trying to find some code which people might have developed which I can use?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to run within your app you would need to design a copy from scratch unfortunately there's nothing built in to just call this as a view.

If you want to redirect people to call a number you can use the following:

```
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:0123456789"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL]];
```

The best way to design it is pretty straightforward as you already have access to it, that screenshot and photoshop would be the way forward, though I'm not sure you'd get through the app store approval process using that.

The below is a pretty nice control I've used myself before, take a look https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jcdialpad

Comment: Really like the control!

Comment: Looks good doesn't it, it's pretty straightforward to customize too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild it yourself, but this might help you out for the code:
https://github.com/hbang/Dialer